# Extract domain from sub domain in C

Tags: c, parsing, dns

I am parsing a DNS Query packet in C. I need to extract domain from the host in query name.

For example:

https://www.google.com --> google.com
http://www.google.co.in --> google.co.in
http://maps.google.com --> google.com
www.abc.xyz --> abc.xyz

From what I've researched, I need to parse the TLDs from sources like https://publicsuffix.org and can use sscanf/regex for getting the domain name.

Is there any way to do it without using the suffix list?

Comment: There's not. That's the point of having a suffix list.

Comment: So, should I make an sscanf format using the suffixes?

Answer (score 1):

Im afraid not: without the suffi list you cannot reliably determine if `http://www.google.co.in` should produce `google.co.in` or `co.in`

Regarding the method, for a simplistic one, you should load the suffix list into a hash table or a sorted table.  Determine the last suffix with `strrchr()` and previous suffixes by scanning for `'.'` by hand.  The first combination of suffixes that is not present on the list, but has a suffix that is, is the domain name.

The rules described in the list published at https://publicsuffix.org are more elaborate.  I suggest looking for publicly available source code or libraries to handle this matching rather than attempting to write your own matcher.  Unless you are quite proficient in C or have this as an assignment.

Comment: I've looked into URI parser and HTParse, but can just extract the host, not the domain from the host.

Answer (score 0):

Building some sort of search tree for the suffix list instead of iterating make sense. [reg-dom lib](https://github.com/usrflo/registered-domain-libs/tree/master/C) does just that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "regdom.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    assert(argc > 1);
    void *tree = loadTldTree();

    char *domain = getRegisteredDomainDrop(argv[1], tree, 1);
    printf("Domain suffix is %s\n", domain ? domain : "Unknown");

    freeTldTree(tree);
}
```